# Rest api return elements outside the filter

Tags: 2013, rest, filter, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm having some problems with my filter / rest call.

I'm trying to get the items that match some criteria in a list but it returns way to much.

```
?$select=Employee_x0020_No_&$filter((Employee_x0020_No_ eq '101009') or (Employee_x0020_No_ eq '101030') or (Employee_x0020_No_ eq '101076') or (Employee_x0020_No_ eq '101077') or (Employee_x0020_No_ eq '103055'))&$top=5000
```

As you can see im trying to get all records where Employee_x0020_No_ (Employee No_ ) is equal to one of these numbers `101009,101030,101076,101077,103055`.

It current returns over 2000 items, when I filter the list itself by these parameters it should only return 57 items.

[image]

As you can see in the image the first item it returns has `Employee_x0020_No_` = `102109`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `=` sign after `filter`.

Try below query:

```
?$select=Employee_x0020_No_&$filter=((Employee_x0020_No_ eq '101009') or (Employee_x0020_No_ eq '101030') or (Employee_x0020_No_ eq '101076') or (Employee_x0020_No_ eq '101077') or (Employee_x0020_No_ eq '103055'))&$top=5000
```

Comment: I have some problem with my filter query/rest call.

?$select=Student_x0020_No,Title,Principal,Student_x0020_Level,Email,ID&$filter=((Student_x0020_No eq '138635')and (isActive eq 1))&$top=5000
This contains more then 5000 records. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @akshay what error message are you getting?